# Ffmpeg lost audio stream

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using the follow command to change brightness of a video, add an image overlay and two text overlays, I probably must make an audio stream var somewhere but I do not know where.

CMD:

-i srcVideoPath

-i logoPath

-filter_complex
eq=contrast=1:brightness=0.3475048:saturation=1:gamma=1:gamma_r=1:gamma_g=1:gamma_b=1:gamma_weight=1[v];

[1:v]scale=h=-1:w=100[overlay_scaled],[v][overlay_scaled]overlay=eval=init:x=W-100-W*0.1:y=W*0.1[v];

[v]drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='name':fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-(text_h*2)-(h*0.1):enable='between(t,0,2)',

drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='function':fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-text_h-(h*0.1)+25:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v]

-preset ultrafast

-map [v]

-acodec copy

outPath

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `-map [v]`, add `-map 0:a:?`. This tells ffmpeg to include the audio streams from the first file, if there are any.

Comment: I will try and let you know how it went, I had the impression -acodec copy does the same.

Comment: `-acodec copy` sets the audio codec mode to copy, but it doesn't select streams for inclusion.

Comment: That makes sense, is there another alternative instead of map ? Like to just copy the stream so it takes less time ? Or map will just do that for me ? (copy the stream in the default format).

Comment: map only decides if the stream is handled; acodec decides how it is handled, and you've already set it to copy.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Much appreciated. The combination is what I am looking for then.

Comment: Yes I added as you suggested the map bellow it. Works like a charm !